# Car won't start, not cranking, but everything else works

Tags: ignition, mercedes-benz, no-crank-no-start, engine-system-service-required

I have a Mercedes-Benz C220 CDI 2003 model. Last night I wanted to go out, so I started the car. Then I forgot to put it in neutral, because sometimes it won't come out of park. When I switched it out of park to put it neutral, from then it wouldn't start. No crank at all everything else works but not starting. What could be going on?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! If you put it back into park, will it start? I have a feeling the problem is the neutral safety switch is not getting engaged correctly or has gone out. It detects when the transmission is in neutral/park and won't let it start if it's not. Secondly, is the check engine light showing? If so, what are the codes? MB has a fairly good diagnostic program ... it can tell you a lot of things.

Comment: If i put it back in park it still not starting,, and where do i find the neutral safety switch? The check engine light is not showing,

Comment: And the funny thing is if i short the starter the engine swings, but with the key um getting nothing

Comment: I haven't found out **exactly** where it's at, however, from what I have found, it should be on the side of the transmission.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds a lot like your ESM is bad (electric shifter module) or EGS (transmissiom control module).

When you move the shifter does the PRNDL on intrument cluster display properly? It will not crank unless it knows it is in P or N.

The EGS around this year have a bad problem of transmission fluid wicking up the wiring and filling the module with fluid. If you catch it early usually you can clean it out and be ok. This is easy to check so worth doing first.  Its usually under the hood in the black box next to the ECM (engine control module).  Un hook it, pull it out, turn it upside down and check around the pins for moisture/oil. If you see some then open it up and clean it up.

Comment: Yes prndl is displaying fine,

Comment: And the selector box on it follows the position of shifter?

Comment: It is working the same way it used to,,

Comment: Usually when esm or egs is having trouble you will notice errors with the prndl but I would still check the egs to be safe. It only takes 5 minutes.

Comment: Ok let me try it

Comment: Okay let me try it

Comment: I did check that,, and still i can't get anything

Comment: then its likely in the esm or a switch in the shifter itself similar to what @Paulster2 suggested.